# PHP script from a tutorial not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Good evening! I believe I might have a problem with my php setup. I installed 
XAMPP and at the same time added mysql. I have taken code from website http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html setting up the mysql database, the main_login.php, checklogin.php (with user and password info added), login_success.php, and checklogin.php through cut and paste.  I am assuming that the code is correct. I saved them into a folder C:\xampp\htdocs\UnnamedSite2. When I attempt to run the code, after entering the user name and password, I get the following:

Notice: Undefined index: myusername in C:\xampp\htdocs\UnnamedSite2\checklogin.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: mypassword in C:\xampp\htdocs\UnnamedSite2\checklogin.php on line 15
Wrong Username or Password

What might be the problem?

main_login.php

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="web"; // Mysql username 
$password="foo.bar"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>

<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
```

login_success.php

```
<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Put your the `<form></form>` tags outside of `<table></table>`. It's easy to make mistake if you mix the form tags with the table elements.

Comment: @frz3993, that shouldn't make a difference and isn't necessary.

Comment: To the OP:  I don't see any reason those $_POST vars wouldn't exist, but this tutorial is outdated.  You should be avoiding mysql_* functions and real_escape_string and be using PDO/mysqli with prepared statements.

Comment: @Devon: actually, it makes a difference - [unexpected markup in tables is handled in surprising ways](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unexpected-markup-in-tables). (Invalid HTML causes problems, who'd have seen that coming?)

Comment: I swapped the form tags. It acted the same. I have no clue how to do the PDO/mysqli suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Expression web 4. When I ran the code in Dremweaver, and replaced the deprecated global sessions, everything started working. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

The error means there are no 'myusername' and 'mypassword' in your $_POST array. Try adding this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Somewhere in your checklogin script to check the contents of said variable.

It will help debugging

Comment: I added it to the first line after the ,?php. I got: array(0) { }

Answer (score -1):

i cannot see your error but this one :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

(to make error disappear)

Comment: Closing your eyes and pretending the error doesn't exist won't make it go away. It won't make the code run properly either.

Comment: @DCoder i agree with you  but  i prefer to ignore uninitialized variable error, in this case, 'myusername'  is uninitialized, other error will show as usual

Comment: @Yassuki However, in this case it means $_POST isn't being populated... hence te uninitialized variable. Warning and notices are there for a reason. Ignoring errors is (almost) never a good option.